# NSURLSession Download Task - Xamarin iOS F#

Tags: c#, f#, xamarin.ios, nsurlsession, completionhandler

I'm trying to implement the following method from the `C#` Xamarin.IOS in `F#`:

```
NSUrlSession.SharedSession.CreateDownloadTask(Request, (data, response, error) => 
    {
        if(response == null)
        {
            Client.FailedWithError(this, error);
        }
        else
        {
            Client.ReceivedResponse(this, response, NSUrlCacheStoragePolicy.Allowed);
            Client.DataLoaded(this, data);
            Client.FinishedLoading(this);
        }
    });
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlSession.CreateDataTask/p/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlRequest/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlSessionResponse/

It's basically a `NSUrlSession` `downloadTask` task with a completionHandler. I know how to implement the first part, but I have no idea what the syntax for the completion handler is and I can't find it anywhere online. This is what I have:

```
let session : NSUrlSession = NSUrlSession.SharedSession
let request : NSUrlRequest = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(url)
let downloadTask : NSUrlSessionDownloadTask = session.CreateDownloadTask(request, ??????)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F#, you can use the `fun ... -> ...` syntax to create a lambda function. Just like in C#, this will be automatically converted to an appropriate delegate in most cases, but if you need to create a delegate explicitly, you can use `MyDelegate(fun ... -> ...)`.

I don't have Xamarin iOS installed, but my guess is that the following should work:

```
NSUrlSession.SharedSession.CreateDownloadTask(Request, fun data response error ->
  if (response = null) then
    Client.FailedWithError(this, error)
  else
    Client.ReceivedResponse(this, response, NSUrlCacheStoragePolicy.Allowed)
    Client.DataLoaded(this, data)
    Client.FinishedLoading(this)
)
```

In F#, arguments of the function are separated by spaces (not by commas), unless you are explicitly taking a tuple, which should not be the case for normal delegates.

If you needed to specify overload (because F# cannot infer it automatically), then you can use:

```
NSUrlSession.SharedSession.CreateDownloadTask
  (Request, NSUrlSessionResponse(fun data response error ->
  // ...
  ) 
)
```

Assuming the delegate you want to create is `NSUrlSessionResponse` - I'm not sure which of the overloads you're calling so you'll need to check that.

Comment: how can I return a value from the closure? I have all this code embedded in a method which must return a `UIImage`. The image is currently being generated within the closure, and I must be able to return it.  I have updated the question with the way I do it currently, however, I don't think this is correct as the closure will execute after the remainder of the method, since the closure must wait for the download to complete first

Comment: @Alk I think that's better answered as a separate question - and please provide all the details about what you want to do with the value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520528/execute-code-on-main-thread-from-async-f